# Ignite Scan Query Issue

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I am using Ignite to store cache values with K-V being of type String-String in a cache named "DOCIDS".

I am using a binary converted object of HashMap as values in another K-V cache named "URLS". The key will be string only but the value will be of "com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteObject".

Now when I query a scan operation I'm doing like this

```java
//This scan query should only happen on cache which has K-V types as String-String.
        public Object scan(Object... allObjects) throws Exception {
            Set<Object> matchedKeys = new HashSet<>();
            try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<String, String>> cursor =
                         cacheHolder.getSecondaryCache().query(new ScanQuery<>(
                                 (k, v) -> k.contains(allObjects[0].toString())
                         ))) {
                for (Cache.Entry<String, String> entry : cursor) {
                    matchedKeys.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
            return matchedKeys;
        }
```

In the allObjects, the value will be everytime of some String pattern. That is for sure. But when Ignite is sifting through the values, somewhere the value is being IgniteObject type, which I'm not inserting in the first place in "DOCIDS" cache. The exception is attached below:

```
"com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.ScrapyIgniteException: IGNITE EXCEPTION :: Exception while scanning for keys with given pattern in Ignite db - DOCIDS. Exception - IDSCaused by: javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to execute query on node [query=GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteQuery$QueryObject$$Lambda$243/2029270129@58665d95, transform=null, part=null, incMeta=false, pageSize=1024, timeout=0, incBackups=false, forceLocal=false, dedup=false, prj=org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupAdapter@1dfc48e7, keepBinary=false, subjId=0ef0942f-d2d1-4ac0-aa5b-783b3e1a0960, taskHash=0, mvccSnapshot=null, dataPageScanEnabled=null], rdc=null, trans=null], nodeId=f01b04de-66c0-4edc-8efe-4977ecf656b1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1272)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.next(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:167)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$5.onHasNext(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:645)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:44)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.AutoClosableCursorIterator.hasNext(AutoClosableCursorIterator.java:47)
    at com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteQuery$QueryObject.scan(IgniteQuery.java:103)
    at com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteQuery.executeFieldsQuery(IgniteQuery.java:47)
    at com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteConnectionHandler$CacheHolder.scanKeys(IgniteConnectionHandler.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteObject
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:643)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:177)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3050)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:52)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:44)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:232)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1142)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:591)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1635)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1255)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4300(GridIoManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$8.execute(GridIoManager.java:1144)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.scrapy.common.ignite.IgniteObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Can someone please explain why Ignite is getting IgniteObject from Cache DOCIDS? Because I'm only storing the IgniteObject in "URLS" cache but not in "DOCIDS". The actual exception is that it's not loading class IgniteObject. I'm not even sure why it's not able to load because I could insert those Objects without any issues.

The IgniteObject class is as follows

```java
import org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObject;
import org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectBuilder;
import java.io.Serializable;

//If value is not String, every value of K-V Store should wrap its contents with this Object
public class IgniteObject implements Serializable {

    //Value set via Reflection
    private Object object;

    public static BinaryObject convertToBinaryObject(Object object) throws Exception{
        //IgniteConnectionHandler.getConnection() will get Ignite Object named ignite. getObjectBuilder will do ignite.binary().builder(stringValue)
        BinaryObjectBuilder builder = IgniteConnectionHandler.getConnection().getObjectBuilder(IgniteObject.class.getName());
        builder.setField("object", object);//No I18N
        return builder.build();
    }

    public Object getActualObject(){
        return object;
    }
}
```

Note: cacheHolder.getSecondaryCache() will give the object - IgniteCache.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting both key and value in `Cache.Entry`, even if you only use key, that happens eagerly.

You can try

```
cacheHolder.getSecondaryCache().withKeepBinary().query(...)
```

to avoid the need of `IgniteObject` class.

Comment: I only need to get keys of some pattern. But it's asking both types to be given. I didn't understand when you say "Happens eagerly". I will surely try that but I want to understand the concept underneath it. when you do a query like that does it mean that it'll get other cache values also?

Comment: Yes, Scan Query always gets both key and value

Comment: But why I am getting a value of type "IgniteObject" from that cache DOCIDS. It should be only String right? And what does "withKeepBinary" does?

Comment: You're getting an entry, which contains `IgniteObject` as value, even if you never use it. `withKeepBinary()` will use `BinaryObject` instead.

Comment: Oh okay I understand. But I am not inserting values of type IgniteObject in DOCIDS cache. And the scan query I asked for is on DOCIDS cache. In that cache, I also only insert K-V as String-String. Does this mean, scan query will run down on all the values of all caches?